# Why does the installing partition creator add free space at the beginning and end of my disks?

Tags: partitioning, ubuntu-core

When I create partitions manually it automatically adds a section of free space (usually 1 MB) in front of the first partition and another one (a couple hundred kB) at the end of each disk. Removing them proves futile.

What is the purpose of these spaces?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the 1MB block at the beginning of the block is likely the bootloader.  uboot is frequently used in Linux distributions and a 1MB block is pretty standard to leave in that location.

Not sure as to the hundreds of KB left at the end of each disk though.  It could be several things, especially if you have a larger block size set which leaves that space as a remainder.

Comment: I thought the bootloader was part of `/boot` (which is always my first partition).